# Access a view helper for a model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Adult model with a name attribute.

If the user is logged in, I want the Adult.name to only return the first name.

Is there a way to have helpers tied to a model where you could specify Adult.helper.name?

Or a least have helpers namespaced to a model?

Answer (score 11):

Just explicitly include the helper in your model

```
# app/helpers/adults_helper.rb
module AdultsHelper
  def say_hello
    "hello, world!"
  end
end

# app/models/adult.rb
class Adult < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AdultsHelper

end
```

Test in console

```
$ script/console
>> a = Adult.new
# => #<Adult id:...>
>> a.say_hello
# => "hello, world!"
```

Comment: interesting, I like this approach.

I may have to think of the best way to name it... maybe Adult.public_name ?

Comment: this does create a problem when I try to generate links in the helper since I get the error: "undefined method `polymorphic_path"

Answer (score 2):

in your Adult model you can add

```
def name
  self.first_name
end
```

so when you find an Adult, like

```
a = Adult.last
puts a.name #will print a.first_name
```

Well, for a better explanation.. paste some code!

Comment: the trouble with this is that if I wanted to display the whole name or first name based on whether the user was logged in (authlogic) I would need to add that condition in every instance where I pulled the user's name