# Use a Rails helper in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, view-helpers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access a view helper for a model in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706433/access-a-view-helper-for-a-model-in-rails)

I know this is probably not something I should do often, but I want to use a helper within a model.

I'm generating a spreadsheet in a Report model and would like to use the `time_ago_in_words` method in `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`

Is this doable, or should I be generating it in a view?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+helper+in+model

Comment: actually, this is precisely what I was looking for.  The search query implying that this is a duplicate did not turn up anything as helpful.

Comment: This works better for me: `ApplicationController.helpers.my_helper_method`

Source: http://makandracards.com/makandra/1307-how-to-use-helper-methods-inside-a-model

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just include the module in the model, and use it like you would in a view

```
class Report
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
  ...
end
```

Comment: What if you only want to use one method from the helper module, and you don't want to `include` the whole thing? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  def my_test_method(a, include_seconds = false)
    time_ago_in_words(a, include_second)
  end

 end
```